# using std::string disables program output

Tags: c++, windows-10, mingw, stdstring

Whenever I use `std::string` to declare a string variable in c++ it prevents the program from outputting anything. for example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello";
    // std::string s;
    return 0;
}
```

This will output `Hello` to the command-line as it should do.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello";
    std::string s;
    return 0;
}
```

This will not output anything (and no errors) since i'm declaring a variable using std::string
I'm using the minGW compiler on a Windows 10 64bit machine

Comment: What are your compiler arguments in both cases, also how are you running this example in both cases? From the command line?

Comment: `std::cout << "Hello\n";`

Comment: I'm running via cmd yes. filename's 'sandbox.cpp' so I use:
`g++ sandbox.cpp -o sandbox`
Then:
`sandbox.exe`

Comment: Simple typo error. @M.M pointed out you forgot the `\n` in the second code, this will likely mean your console buffer is not flushed before the program ends.

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work. same result with `std::cout << "Hello\n";`   
as with `std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;`

Comment: Maybe there is a bug with your compiler installation and it is failing to start the executable. Try launching the executable from windows run / command prompt (i.e. outside whatever shell you're using)

Comment: The mingw compiler is pretty ancient and buggy, you should use mingw-w64

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try that